# Communicate with DynamoDB API when server is behind HTTP Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

so I've recently put a dev server behind authentication, meaning anyone that wants to dive into that domain needs to give a username and password or get a 401.

I'm helping build a game in Unity3d, and in order to communicate with this server, I just supply the url as such:

```
https://username:password@/host/url/here
```

For dev purposes it works.

I've done some moving around, and it seems DynamoDB (done through the PHP SDK) isn't playing nice, and I'd like to know if it's because the dev server is behind authentication, and if that is a problem, how to allow interaction with the Amazon.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood of your question, your application looks like this:

```
     authentication
         layer
           |
 incoming  |     +--------+  outgoing
   HTTP    |     |        |  DDB call
-----------+---->+ Server +------------>
           |     |        |
           |     +--------+ 
           |
```

That is to say, You authenticate incoming HTTP requests. When your application issues a call to DynamoDB, It acts as a client and not as a server. Let's say your client is behind a Firewall. Nothing will prevent him from issuing requests to your server and get the response back. This same reasoning applies to your server when it calls DynamoDB.

So, If there is a problem with DynamoDB PHP SDK, it should not be related to the API call itself.

Comment: Turned out to be something else. Thank you for taking the time to draw up that excellent diagram.